# Dandelion Datatables Filter causes error

Tags: jsp, datatables, dandelion

I am trying to migrate from Dandelion Datatables 0.10.0 to 1.1.0

I have one  filter in web.xml file

```
<!-- Dandelion filter definition and mapping -->
<filter>
  <filter-name>dandelionFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.github.dandelion.core.web.DandelionFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>dandelionFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

It gives me this error

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: STRICT_DUPLICATE_DETECTION
at com.github.dandelion.core.web.handler.debug.AbstractDebugPage.<clinit>(AbstractDebugPage.java:71)
at com.github.dandelion.core.web.handler.debug.StandardDebugMenu.getPages(StandardDebugMenu.java:45)
at com.github.dandelion.core.Context.initDebugMenus(Context.java:620)
at com.github.dandelion.core.Context.init(Context.java:158)
at com.github.dandelion.core.Context.<init>(Context.java:131)
at com.github.dandelion.core.web.DandelionFilter.init(DandelionFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4574)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5184)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1387)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strict duplication detection feature was added in [Jackson-Core 2.3. See http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser.Feature.html#STRICT_DUPLICATE_DETECTION](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser.Feature.html#STRICT_DUPLICATE_DETECTION)

I upgraded this jar files and issue solved.

1. jackson-annotations-2.7.4.jar
2. jackson-core-2.7.4.jar
3. jackson-databind-2.7.4.jar